# How to add REGEX in a string inside a shell script?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sh

The following command detects if any of the staged files in git is `myFile.js`:

```
echo $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | egrep 'path/to/myFile.jsx?$')
```

But I want to detect any `.js` file in that folder. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
echo $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | egrep 'path/to/{*}.jsx?$')
```

How to add a wild card for the filename here?

Comment: You should almost never use `echo $(somecommand)` -- the `echo` and the `$( )` mostly cancel each other out, except for some potential parsing weirdnesses in between them. Just run the command directly (unless you want those parsing weirdnesses for some reason).

Comment: thanks, I was just echoing for debugging purposes, in the actual code the whole part after the echo is set as a var @GordonDavisson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
egrep 'path/to/{*}.jsx?$'
```

with:

```
egrep 'path/to/.+\.jsx?$'
```